# Passing a string to function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have next two functions:

```
    def encrypt(self, text):
        for i in range(len(text)):
            text = text[:i] + self.letters[self.letters.index(text[i]) + self.key] + text[i+1:]

    def decrypt(self, text):
        for i in range(len(text)):
            text = text[:i] + self.letters[self.letters.index(text[i]) - self.key] + text[i+1:]
```

I want them to act on strings in-place. What should I do?

Comment: Please edit and ask the question. Dont understand what you mean

Comment: You cannot change stringds in place - string are not mutable in python - you can only create a new string

Comment: @Ekure What don't you understand? I understand it perfectly well. Maybe you missed the last sentence?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, a string is immutable. You cannot overwrite the values of immutable objects. However, you can assign the variable again.

Comment: But it's ineffective. There is something like passing by reference(c++) in python, isn't it?

Comment: @silly_willy [Python doesn't support pass-by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/4518341).

Comment: Arguments are passed by assignment. If you pass an immutable object to a method, you still can't rebind the outer reference, and you can't even mutate the object.